# PlayerPrefs in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, sharedpreferences

I have a Unity game imported to my Android Studio project. That way, I can start the game by accessing the generated class "Unity Player Class".
In my unity game, I wrote a code that saves the current scene in PlayerPrefs:

```
public void SharedPrefsPlayerThing()
{
    Scene currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
    buildIndex = currentScene.buildIndex;

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Scene", buildIndex);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

How can I now get this "Scene" key in Android Studio and save it in Shared Prefrences?
I know that in Unity it's just PlayerPrefs.GetInt but since there is no player prefs in Android Studio, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You do have the option of using the new Data Store, though it is still in alpha, documentation can be found here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore.

But to use shared preference you can do something like this, you need a Shared Preference file name and property name can be simple final values in code. I am assuming you are using Java and not kotlin so here is a short sample in Java

```
// Get the shared preferences editor to save changes
SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPrefsEditor = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

// Store the integer to the shared preference
sharedPrefsEditor.putInt(PREFERENCE_KEY_NAME, YOUR_VALUE).apply();
```

And to access the value

```
// Get the shared preferences File
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//Retrieving the value
Integer value = sharedPrefs.getInt(PREFERENCE_KEY_NAME, A_DEFAULT_VALUE_CAN_BE_NULL);
```

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure I understand how to use this. I don't have the name of my shared preferences file so I used getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE) instead. However, what am I supposed to put in "PREFERENCE_KEY_NAME, YOUR_VALUE"? I need to get the value from my Unity Player class in which the value is stored in PlayerPrefs.

Could you please show me how to use it?

Comment: I am not sure what file name unity will create for you, but if that file name is constant, you can view the file name in device file explorer, it would be on the bottom right panel of Android Studio if you have default settings. When you open Device file explorer search for data -> data -> your-package-name -> shared_prefs. Look for each file, you should be able to find the unity generated file there (if unity uses Shared Preferences). If you don't find the file there, then Unity is not using shared preferences. Also to be able to view the package the apk has to be debuggable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I found my PlayerPrefs file, but it doesn't contain the "Scene" key. How can I access it in Android Studio?
https://gyazo.com/301f5969598c2973010a6010630701f6

Comment: you only have access to the those values, as you see in the shared pref file map, you can access each of those values, by their keys, there is Good Chance Unity is masking the value, in any case, you can always look at method definition to see what unity is doing and reverse engineer it.